# How would I go about getting text entry from Glade in GTK?

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, glade

I am working on trying to get Text input from my text entry fields to an array. I have 8 text entry fields and have been following many of the tutorials. So far from what I gathered . I have

```
void on_Save_and_Process_button_clicked(GTKButton *button, GtkEntry *text){

GTKWidget *entry1 = lookup_widget(text,"entry1");

Const g char *entry_text1 = gtk_entry _get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry1));

}
```

I am getting an warning in:

```
GTKWidget *entry1 = lookup_widget(text,"entry1");
```

That says:

warning: intialization make pointer from integer without a cast

This my first GTK project. Any help,guidance, links to tutorials of similar projects would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more details on the function lookup_widget (). I expect it is returning an integer and you are assigning that to a pointer.

Comment: To my understanding this the look_up function helps obtain already existing widgets.  

" i) Variables of ‘GtkWidget’ type are declared and pointers to already existing widgets are obtained using the lookup_widget()"

I got this bit from this tutorial.

http://wingtk.sourceforge.net/ishan/glade.html

Comment: The tutorial that you are using does not define what lookup_widget () is and it is not a Gtk function . I assume that it is not in any header so the compilier will assume the function returns an int hence your warning.   Don't carry on using that tutorial, it is very out of date with some of the code for GTK 1 we are now on 3 and they are working on 4.

Comment: Thank you very much I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `lookup_widget` was part of Glade 2, a long time ago. Back then, Glade would generate C code, instead of an XML file, and that function was included in the generated code.

You can't even run Glade 2 anymore most likely, so the tutorial you are using is not going to help you very much. Use a more modern tutorial, such as the one included in the official GTK 3.x documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I appreciate the response.